# Listen for ECS failed to place task in Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to create a rule in Cloudwatch that listens for the events when ECS fails to place a task.

I see examples in the AWS documentation about when a task fails, or when the state of a container instance changes. But this is not what I want. I want specifically to listen for when ECS emits the event "failed to place task". I know it will have to be some sort of event pattern that matches it, but I am not sure about the specifics of the event pattern.

This example matches a task state change, but is not what I want. But I think it is similar:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ecs"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "ECS Task State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "lastStatus": [
      "STOPPED"
    ],
    "stoppedReason": [
      "Essential container in task exited"
    ],
    "containers": {
      "exitCode": ["1", "2", "3", and so on...]
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to match the event "failed to place task".

Comment: Would [this workaround](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/121#issuecomment-383090350) suit your needs?

Comment: I think that will work. So, the answer to my question is: you currently cannot do this in Cloudwatch, but there is a workaround using Lambda, and this feature has been requested from AWS and they are working on implementing it. Yeah? If you type that up I'll mark the question as answered with your response! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently cannot do this in Cloudwatch, but there is a [workaround](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/121#issuecomment-383090350) using Lambda. This feature has been requested from AWS and they are working on implementing it.

Comment: I created a gist with code that works in Lambda running python 3.7
Just schedule it to run every minute or so to check for failed placements.
[failed_to_place_task](https://gist.github.com/adamkgray/4b25669d84760ed24e129020b57fab96)
It has no dependencies and is short so it can be in-lined in a CFN template even.